# How to autostart and resume any download in Bittorrent as soon as system starts?

Tags: bittorrent

I want Transmission Bittorrent to resume download as soon as system starts and any other download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `transmission-gtk -m &` on the end of your `~/.profile` file. This will start Transmission on the start up and the -m stands for minimized. Transmission should continue where he left off after he starts.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `transmission-gtk` to the start up list:

1. Open the dash and type *"Startup Application"*
2. Click *"Add"*.
3. Write a *"Name" for the application, write the following in *"Command"* `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk`, if you want you can write a comment.
4. Click *"Add"*, close, restart your session and *Voila*!